# Intel INDE - How to control (mute) microphone input volume (input gain) in Android

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager, intelinde

I'm using Intel INDE for video streaming purposes (Android) and it's giving me headaches to solve some problems.

The main problem is how to mute/unmute the devices microphone in Android.

Looks like Intel INDE is overriding the input volume to be always active.
The only way I found is to not set the AudioFormatAndroid of Intel INDE API deleting these lines:

```
audioFormat = new AudioFormatAndroid("audio/mp4a-latm", 44100, 1);
capture.setTargetAudioFormat(audioFormat);
```

The problem is that I need to do it during the streaming, not before.

Therefore I tried to manage microphone input settings like:

```
AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, isMuteON);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, isMuteON);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, isMuteON);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, isMuteON);
```

It did not work, so i tried to change Stream Volume, doing this:

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

It shows a Toast stating that I muted the volume, but the audio stream is still active on my streaming.

I´ve searched StackOverflow and google about input gain (microphone volume) and found similar problems but none of them gave me a solution to my problem, can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Please check the last comment there: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/542818