# Intel INDE - Video Capturing for Unity 3D (How to Capture only the App Video and Audio instead of using mic)

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, intelinde

Good Day!

I've followed the instruction from this link:
[Intel® INDE Media for Mobile Tutorials - Video Capturing for Unity3d* Applications on Android*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-capturing-for-unity3d-applications?page=4#) and I've made it working with my app. The problem only is that the audio uses the microphone for the recording and it created lots of noise thus producing a lower quality output file. My question is that how can I can just have only the plain video and audio (output of the app) capture? If this is not possible, how can I integrate an audio file to the recorded video? I hope you could give some guides and examples.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you found a workaround for your issue?

Comment: No. I haven't solve this issue.

Comment: Hey ! I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943540/intel-inde-how-to-control-mute-microphone-input-volume-input-gain-in-andro?rq=1) where they remove the lines before compiling the plugin with ant:

`audioFormat = new AudioFormatAndroid("audio/mp4a-latm", 44100, 1);
capture.setTargetAudioFormat(audioFormat);`

Have you tested it?